# How manually setup virtual directory? Iis error

Tags: iis

I'm trying to configure my website to IIS but it's a problem with it
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

hosts file
[image: hosts file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to web project properties;
2. Enable ckeckbox "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)"
3. Select in dropdown list - "Local IIS"
4. Add project url and click the button "Create virtual directory"